# I am writing a code that determines the type of triangle (equilateral, scalene, isosceles) by getting the length of each side from the user

Tags: java

This is what I have so far. It compiles and runs but only until the user puts in the side of each length. After the information is put in, the program should tell the user what triangle it is, but its not.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //declare scanner

public class SideClassification {

public static void main(String [] args) 
{

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //declare scanner

//declare sides of triangle
int sideA = 0;
int sideB = 0;
int sideC = 0;

System.out.print ("Enter the length of side A: "); //ask user for length of side A
sideA = input.nextInt();

System.out.print ("Enter the length of side B: "); //ask user for length of side B
sideB = input.nextInt();

System.out.print ("Enter the length of side C: "); //ask user for lenght of side C
sideC = input.nextInt();  

}

public static boolean isEqualateral (int sideA, int sideB, int sideC) //if statement for equalateral triangle
{
if ((sideA == sideB) && (sideB == sideC))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
}

public static boolean isIsoceles (int sideA, int sideB, int sideC) //if statement for isoceles triangle
{
if((sideA == sideB) || (sideA == sideC) || (sideB == sideC)) 
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
}

public static boolean isScalene (int sideA, int sideB, int sideC) //if statement for scalene triangle
{
if((sideA != sideB) && (sideA != sideC) && (sideB != sideC))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the functions `isEqualateral`, `isIsoceles`, and `isScalene`.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually call the functions:

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //declare scanner
    // Omitted for brevity

    // Call the functions and print results
    if (isEqualateral(sideA, sideB, sideC)) System.out.println("isEqualateral");
    if (isIsoceles(sideA, sideB, sideC)) System.out.println("isIsoceles");
    if (isScalene(sideA, sideB, sideC)) System.out.println("isScalene");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually print the answer in your main method. The last thing you do is get the input, so of course it won't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually call the static method `isEqualateral` (and the ones for the other types) to determine the type:

In your main method after getting the user inputs you should do:

```
if(isEqualateral(sideA,sideB,sideC)) {
    System.out.println("Triangle is equalateral.");
}else if(isScalene(sideA,sideB,sideC)){
    System.out.println("Triangle is scalene.");
}else if(isIsoceles(sideA,sideB,sideC)) {
    System.out.println("Triangle is isoceles.");
}else{
    System.out.println("Unknown type! Check your input");
}
```